# AWSS3 Swift Download Without Saving

Tags: swift, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, nsfilemanager

After **MUCH** pain and confusion I finally have Swift downloading files from S3. Phew...

Im using TransferManager..

```
transferManager.download(downloadRequest).continueWith(executor: AWSExecutor.mainThread(), block: { (task:AWSTask<AnyObject>) -> Any? in

if let error = task.error as? NSError {
    if error.domain == AWSS3TransferManagerErrorDomain, let code = AWSS3TransferManagerErrorType(rawValue: error.code) {
        switch code {
        case .cancelled, .paused:
            break
        default:
            print("Error downloading: \(downloadRequest.key) Error: \(error)")
        }
    } else {
        print("Error downloading: \(downloadRequest.key) Error: \(error)")
    }
    return nil
}
print("Download complete for: \(downloadRequest.key)")
let downloadOutput = task.result
return nil
})
```

This saves the file locally, and I cant seem to get the result as a UIImage to store in an array without saving it locally.. this will cause some serious bloat to my app. How can I just save the file to an array without the need to save it lcoally?

Comment: `This saves the file locally` How? Why? I don't see any code saving the file locally.